# Using premade databases in my app

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a sqlite database that I have made from csv files. What is the best practice to have ma app be able to read from this database? All of the online resources seem to be geared towards the app making the database itself.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This blog article](http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/) gives a pretty good rundown of what you're after.